Is it possible disable the "Go to location" feature when co-authoring in excel?
I managed to implement measures to make it unable for users of the workbook to navigate to other sheets by hiding the tabs and is only accessible to navigate to via vba.  However, I noticed that it is still possible to go into other "restricted sheets" via the little user bubbles in the top right corner of the screen.
Example: sheet1 is only accessible by me, but when I am currently on the sheet, people can still jump in when they click on to my name and select "Go to Location".
Is there a way to disable that feature via vba or any other work around that anyone knows of?
Thank you.
I haven't tried anything as I have completely no idea where to start with this.

Directly restricting the "Go to Location" feature via VBA is not possible due to the limitations of the Excel object model.
The best workaraund I could come-up with is the following function. You could extend it by looking up the user and have a list of users (yourself) that are allowed to change sheet.
If you have several allowed sheets consider using
allowedSheets = Array("AllowedSheet1", "AllowedSheet2", "AllowedSheet3")

And iterate over them.
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim allowedSheetName As String
    allowedSheetName = "Sheet1" ' Set the name of your allowed sheet here

    ' Check if the current sheet is not the allowed sheet
    If Sh.Name <> allowedSheetName Then
        ' Notify the user
        MsgBox "You are not allowed to navigate to this sheet. Redirecting you to the allowed sheet."

        ' Redirect the user to the allowed sheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(allowedSheetName).Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


Thank you for the prompt response!  This looks very promising, I will give this a shot.  I'm going to need a database of users and their respective clearance but this just might work.  Thank you again!

@Cealizar Serrano I am just curious how did it go for you? Could you maybe share your final solution?

I posted what I did below.

This seem to have worked for me. First make a function to find the range of authorised users.
Public Function GetUserRng() As Long
    GetUserRng = Users.Range("D3").End(xlDown).row
End Function

Then a function to authenticate them
Public Function Authentication() As String
    Dim Stafflink As Variant
        Stafflink = Users.Range("C4:E" & GetUserRng)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Stafflink, 1)
        If Stafflink(i, 1) = Environ("Username") Then
            Authentication = Stafflink(i, 3)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Then these subs in ThisWorkBook
Private Function IsInArray(Val As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim Element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError:
    For Each Element In arr
        If Element = Val Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
IsInArray = False
End Function


Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim AllowedSheets() As Variant
    If Authentication = "King" Then
        AllowedSheets = Array(KingSheets)
    ElseIf Authentication = "Peasant" Then
        AllowedSheets = Array(PeasantSheets)
    ElseIf Authentication = "Concubine" Then
        AllowedSheets = Array(Concubine sheets)
    Else: AllowedSheets = Array(Enemyofthestate)
    End If

    If IsInArray(Sh.Name, AllowedSheets) = True Then
    'Do nothing
    Else
        If Authentication = "GodLevel" Then
        'Do nothing
        Else: Call PageOfRedirection
            MsgBox "You don't have clearance to access this sheet. Contact Master, ext 42069"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

